# why prolog is entering infinite loop?

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

I made this code so basically, it detects if the array in the first argument is the reverse array in the second argument, it works well but when I want to have the reversed array for a giving array, first it gives me the right answer than if I do ";" to have another answer I expect to get false which is normal, but Prolog just enters an infinite loop.

here is my code :

```
rev([],[]).
rev([X|A],B):- append(C,[X],B), rev(A,C) .
```

and this is a test to explain the problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diJpw.png)

```
?- rev([4,3,9,9],[9,9,3,4]).
true ;
false.

?- rev([4,3,9,9],[4,2,1,4]).
false.

?- rev([4,3,9,9],Result).
Result = [9, 9, 3, 4] ;
.
.
.

Waiting for Prolog. Close again to force termination.
```

Comment: See notes at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=reverse/2 , and click on the orange circle to see the code: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#reverse/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, is this such a big problem? From time to time you do not get a clear response from Prolog but instead it just loops. So sometimes it behaves like a runaway engine. Certainly not ideal. But it could be worse! In particular, if it would produce an **incorrect answer**. Like failing, when there are solutions.

To understand why Prolog loops in your case, it helps to put some falsework into your program. By adding goals **`false`**. In this manner we will see just the real reason:

```
rev([],[]) :- false.
rev([X|A],B):- append(C,[X],B), false, rev(A,C).

?- rev([4,3,9,9],Result), false.
   loops.
```

Such a program is called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice). The nice property here is that if this failure slice loops, also your original program will loop. But often this slice is much smaller, so the error is easier to detect.

In order to get rid of that looping, you need to modify something in the visible part. One possibility would be to exchange the two goals. This would make this query terminate. But then,

```
rev([],[]) :- false.
rev([X|A],B):- rev(A,C), false, append(C,[X],B).

?- rev(L, [9,9,3,4]), false.
   loops.
```

So by just exchanging goals, things are not solved in general.

To solve this for both cases, *both* lists have to be taken into account prior to the first goal.

```
rev(Xs, Ys) :-
   rev(Xs, Ys, Ys).

rev([], [], []).
rev([X|Xs], Ys, [_|Zs]) :-
   rev(Xs, Xsr, Zs),
   append(Xsr,[X],Ys).
```

So a third argument was added, which ensures that the length of `Ys` may influence termination.

There are actually better more efficient ways to express this. But conceptually this solution is simpler to understand.

Comment: tnx for answering , i am just a beginner in prolog .

Comment: from your final answer (code) what i had understood is you did 2 changes , you first did increase the number of arguments ,than, you did exchange goals , i don't really know their utility , i realize in my previous code that when i request to find a reversed array , append() is going in infinite loop because it searches for 2 variables C&B  (since it is 1st function) , which not logic .since rev() gonna search for C , so there is no need for append() to look for  C , rev() gonna give us C , and append gonna build B , so i must exchange goals to prevent append() to search for C .

Comment: but why this solution is not the best ?

Comment: because it unnecessarily uses recursion (which has a performance & memory impact), and because it uses append to add an element to the the end of a list, which requires going from the start to the end of the list first, which is slow and inefficient when the end of the list can and should be used directly. See my comment above, linking to swi-prolog notes and sourcecode.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rev/2` is invoking `append/3` with two unbound variables. On backtracking, it's generating unbound lists of ever-increasing length:

[image: SWI-Prolog Swish screenshot]

That's a feature of `append/3`.

The "classic" reversal of a list is this:

```
rev( [] , [] ) .
rev( [X|Xs] , Ys ) :- rev(Xs,X1), append(X1,[X],Ys) .
```

It runs on O(N<sup>2</sup>) time. And it will blow the stack given a list of sufficient length. And if the 1st argument to `rev/2` is unbound, you'll go into a recursive loop (until the stack overflows).

Instead, use a helper predicate with an accumulator. It's a common Prolog idiom to have a "public" predicate that does little more than invoke a "private" helper predicate of the same name, but with different arity, where the extra arguments carry the necessary state to accomplish the task at hand.

```
rev( []     , Ys , Ys ) .
rev( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :- rev(Xs,[X|Ts],Ys).
```

Now you have something that is (1) tail recursive, and (2) runs in O(n) time and space.

Once you have that, the "public" `rev/2` is just this:

```
rev( Xs, Ys ) :- rev(Xs,[],Ys) .
```

where we seed the accumulator with the empty list.

Note however, that this `rev/2` is not bi-directional. Invoking `rev(Xs,[a,b,c])` will work successfully, but backtracking into it will result in an infinite recursive loop.

To fix that, simply add some type checking into `rev/2`. To successfully reverse a list, at least one of `Xs` or `Ys` must be bound. That gives us this:

```
rev( Xs , Ys ) :- nonvar(Xs), !, rev( Xs, [] , Ys ) .
rev( Xs , Ys ) :- nonvar(Ys),    rev( Ys, [] , Xs ) .
```

Putting it all together, you get:

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/RdhuxIlF.pl

```
rev( Xs , Ys ) :- nonvar(Xs), !, rev( Xs, [] , Ys ) .
rev( Xs , Ys ) :- nonvar(Ys),    rev( Ys, [] , Xs ) .

rev( []     , Ys , Ys ) .
rev( [X|Xs] , Ts , Ys ) :- rev(Xs,[X|Ts],Ys).
```

Comment: Your suggested improved version, fails for `rev(Xs, Ys)`.

Comment: So, `Xs = [], rev(Xs, Ys)` succeeds correctly, yet `rev(Xs, Ys), Xs = []` fails incorrectly.

Comment: thnx , i don't mind to run it on O(N²) , so the goal exchange is solution

Comment: Also, `rev([a|_],[]).` loops

Answer (score 0):

I liked the creative approach of your code... then I dare to suggest a fix, in plain old style, instead of a rewrite:

```
rev([],[]).
rev([X|A],B):- append(C,[X],B), rev(A,C), !.
```

Comment: `Xs = [X,Y], rev(Xs,Xs).` succeeds correctly, unifying `X = Y`. Yet, `rev(Xs,Xs), Xs = [X,Y].` incorrectly fails.

Comment: @CapelliC tnx , I really appreciate it .